# Windows keeps making annoying noise

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7. I keep getting an annoying noise that happens maybe once or twice an hour. I can live with it but it's really quite off putting when I'm watching a movie or playing a game and this noise occurs.

The noise is like the one where you try to click away from a window on the screen and Windows won't let you and the window flashes.

I have no idea how to fix this, so any help is appreciated. Ty.

Comment: is something trying to install/upgrade itself but does not have permission because of UAC (User Access Control)? Scheduled task? I would check that first, something might be trying to run and can't.

Comment: @Logman How do I check that?

Comment: Use AutoRuns .... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx   you can uncheckmark all listed in the tab. And check services for something that updates itself. BUT be very careful deleting or disabling services.

Comment: If it is the default beep, you could just adjust "System Sounds" down in the audio mixer. But I totally agree with the above, it is likely that something is trying to run, something you are better off knowing, than setting to ignore.

Comment: @Logman I downloaded that and sorry, but I have no idea what I'm looking for. What do I do?

Comment: @KeirBourne run autoruns as administrator, locate the tab "Scheduled Tasks". Select each item and uncheckmark the item.

Comment: @Logman I've done that now and unchecked everything in Scheduled Tasks. However, I just heard the noise again.

Comment: @KeirBourne ok, it might be in the "services" tab... but I wouldn't mess there unless your extremely careful. Second thought, do you have Anti-Virus running? Can you check the AV and see if it found anything? Sometimes an AV will keep trying to get rid of a threat but can not delete it.